# migration from google app engine to google compute engine

Tags: google-app-engine, virtual-machine, scaling, google-compute-engine

So google compute engine was announced yesterday and the prices for processing power are much better than the app engine standards.  Anyone have any idea what the migration would look like  or if we will be able to use the new google compute virtual machines with our current app?

Comment: compute engine is not like GAE. what you are asking is exaclty the same as `how do i migrate my GAE app to EC2`. or `how do i run a gae app on my own server?`. one is a PaaS and the other one is a LaaS

Comment: @aschmid00 on the google blog they say, and I quote, "If you are interested in using VMs with your App Engine applications in the future, let us know by signing up here." so I was wondering if anyone knew what that would look like http://googleappengine.blogspot.com/2012/06/google-compute-engine-launches.html

Comment: `with` does not mean you can migrate an app from gae to a VM. it means you can integrate it **with** your app like cloudSQL or Google Storage

Comment: exactly. do you know anything about that?

Comment: no i don't know if there will be certain apis to integrate your app with a VM on compute engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

At Google IO the team showed a demo where GCE VMs were being dynamically spun up from within a GAE app. I recommend you watch that session and download the code sample to get a better understanding of interop between the two services. The session us posted on YouTube on the Google developers channel there

Comment: here is the link for anyone else who is wondering:  http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ws2VRHq5ars&feature=plcp

Answer (score 1):

App Engine (AE) and Google Compute Engine (GCE) are different tools, so they'll have different specs and pricing models.

With GCE, you can choose how many servers to run, when to run them, what software stack to install on them, etc. It's a lot of power, and not only you *can* choose how to run them, you also *must* choose how to run them.

AE on the other hand makes all of those decisions for you: The running stack, turning servers on and off depending on demand, distributed persistent storage, etc.

So before deciding to migrate the question you have to answer is: Do you want the freedom (and responsibility) of running your whole stack? Or would you rather let App Engine take care of the scalability details, while you focus on coding your app?

Comment: Flipe> Can a MySQL instance that is being used by GAE, be also used by code running in Google Compute Engine VM ? And what about Cloud Storage?

Answer (score 0):

After reading the Answers/comments above, it is now evident that GAE app is not straight-forward ready to be deployed on Compute engine. I fully understand that what all the managed services(mostly as APIs be it, datastore, document/index Search, memcache, cloud storage, task queues, cron jobs etc.), App Engine offered being a platform, won't be the same-fashioned accessible/integration-ready if available on Compute engine at all.

We have a 5 years old fully-grown App engine app now.
I am considering a scenario to support high-level of customization/control and adding third party softwares/middlewares to our server environment which is not possible with App engine. So if we have all solutions(Compute Engines, Container Engines etc.) other than App engine, to migrate our application to meet such requirements, what is the cost of such migration?

1. Need of server provisioning and configuration at Compute engines with different pricing model[Understood, should not be a problem :)]
2. Full or partial code rewrite to continue using the same APIs esp. Datastore, Cloud Storage, Task Queues, Cron jobs, Document Search, Memcache etc.[Need confirmation here and any reference/link to migration guide would be help!!]
3. Does this lead to risk of losing any managed service/API offered from App Engine? Document Search, Memcache, Task Queues, Cron jobs seem the possible candidates. Please confirm.
4. As per my reading, Big Query, Cloud storage, Pub-Sub APIs integration should not be much affected with such migration(Client-libraries or Rest APIs should still help!). Please confirm.

In nut-shell, We wanted it fully managed in the beginning so PaaS seemed the right choice 5 years ago. Now we want App minus platform-managed plus customized/flexible to our choice. How complicated this transition is going to be?